# Reducing the computation time used by parallel table when finding a fixed point

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, parallelization, recursion, iteration

I am using Intel Core(™) processor, 32 bit operating system, 4GB RAM, Windows 7. I am running the following code and it is taking hours to obtain the result. Can any one help me in improving the codes so that it takes less time.

```
μ = 0.01214398779977472`

μ1 = 328823.8592475095`

Subscript[e, 1] = 0.0167`

A = 389.1779396462019`

ϕ = 0

Subscript[e, 2] = 0.0549`

Vx = 
  x + μ/(y^2 + (-1 + x + μ)^2)^(3/2) - x μ/(y^2 + (-1 + x + μ)^2)^(3/2) - 
  μ^2/(y^2 + (-1 + x + μ)^2)^(3/2) - x/(y^2 + (x + μ)^2)^(3/2) - 
  μ/(y^2 + (x + μ)^2)^(3/2) + x μ/(y^2 + (x + μ)^2)^(3/2) + 
  μ^2/(y^2 + (x + μ)^2)^(3/2) + x μ1/(2 A^3) + (3 x μ1 Cos[2 ϕ])/A^3 + 
  (3 y μ1 Sin[2 ϕ])/A^3 - (μ1 Cos[ϕ] Subscript[e, 1]^2)/(2 A^2); 

Vy =
  y - (y μ)/(y^2 + (-1 + x + μ)^2)^(3/2) - y/(y^2 + (x + μ)^2)^(3/2) + 
  (y*μ)/(y^2 + (x + μ)^2)^(3/2) + (y*μ1)/(2 A^3) - (3 y μ1 Cos[2 ϕ])/A^3 + 
  (μ1 Sin[ϕ])/A^2 + (3 x μ1 Sin[2 ϕ])/A^3 - (μ1 Sin[ϕ] Subscript[e, 1]^2)/(2 A^2);

Vxx = D[Vx, x];
Vyy = D[Vy, y];
Vxy = D[Vx, y];
Vyx = D[Vy, x];

newton[{x_, y_}] := 
  {x, y} + 
    {Simplify[-(Vx Vyy - Vy Vxy)/(Vyy Vxx - Vxy^2)], 
     Simplify[(Vx Vyx - Vy Vxx)/(Vyy Vxx - Vxy^2)]};

 sol = 
   {{ 0.188277, -0.9824026}, { 0.188277, 0.9824026}, { 1.152706, 0}, 
    {-0.998550, 0}, { 0.987856, 0}, { 0.835518, 0}, { -0.012144, 0}};

 tab = 
   ParallelTable[
     N[FixedPoint[newton, {i, j}, 10]], 
     {j, -2, 2, 0.003},
     {i, -2, 2, 0.003}]

 rules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{sol, Range[Length[sol]]}];

 newtab = Map[First @ Nearest[rules, #] &, tab, {2}];

 P1 = 
   ArrayPlot[newtab, 
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",  DataReversed -> True]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange. Please consult https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your question. As a first remark: Please post code that can be copied so that other user can 1.) really read it and 2.) experiment with it without needing to retype everything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as others already have stated, an image of the screen is not an acceptable question.  Please edit the question to replace the screen-shot by the code itself in Mathematica format.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle issue with the code in the question is that the definition of `newton` does not replace `x` and `y` in `Vx`, etc. by the values of the arguments of `newton`.  There are a number of ways to resolve this issue, including defining

```
newton[{x1_, y1_}] := {x1, y1} + {Simplify[-(Vx Vyy - Vy Vxy)/(Vyy Vxx - Vxy^2)], 
    Simplify[(Vx Vyx - Vy Vxx)/(Vyy Vxx - Vxy^2)]}/.{{x -> x1, y -> y1}}
```

With this resolved, we can focus on increasing the computational speed.  Since almost all the time goes into repeatedly evaluating `newton`, our effort should go there.  A factor of three or more is obtained by redefining `newton` as

```
newton[{x1_, y1_}] := Block[{}, {vx, vy, vxx, vyy, vxy} = {Vx, Vy, Vxx, Vyy, Vxy} /. 
  {x -> x1, y -> y1}; {x1, y1} + {-(vx vyy - vy vxy), (vx vxy - vy vxx)}/(vyy vxx - vxy^2)]
```

which takes advantage of the fact that `Vxy == Vyx` and also eliminates duplicated evaluations of intermediate results.  Eliminating `Simplify` also saves a bit of time, because it is ineffective in the present calculation.  (`N` in the definition of `tab` also can be eliminated, because it has no effect, but doing so saves negligible time.)  With these changes, the computation completes in about eleven minutes on my four-processor PC, yielding

[image]

Perhaps, restructuring `Vx`, `Vy`, and their derivatives could save a bit more time.

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues:

1. `newton` does not replace `x` and `y`. (See [bbgrodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey)'s answer.)
2. Every call to `newton` calls also a `Simplify` which is pretty slow. Simplifying it once at the time of definition should suffice.

You can resolve point 1 and 2 by defining:

```
 newton[{x_, y_}] := 
  Evaluate[{x, y} + {Simplify[-(Vx Vyy - Vy Vxy)/(Vyy Vxx - Vxy^2)], 
     Simplify[(Vx Vyx - Vy Vxx)/(Vyy Vxx - Vxy^2)]}];
```

Even that is probably still too slow. Compiling the code helps and it makes parallelization easier.

```
With[{xnew = N@newton[{x, y}][[1]], ynew = N@newton[{x, y}][[2]]}, 
  newtonize = Compile[{{x0, _Real, 1}, {maxiter, _Integer}},
     Block[{x, y, xbuffer},
      x = Compile`GetElement[x0, 1];
      y = Compile`GetElement[x0, 2];
      Do[
       xbuffer = xnew;
       y = ynew;
       x = xbuffer;
       ,
       {maxiter}];
      {x, y}],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
  ];
```

This `CompiledFunction` performs `maxiter` iterations on each input vector. Note that we use the option `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` which creates a `CompiledFunction` that threads automatically over the matrix `x0data` of starting vectors below:

```
sol = Developer`ToPackedArray[N[{{0.188277, -0.9824026}, {0.188277, 0.9824026}, {1.152706, 0.}, {-0.998550, 0.}, {0.987856, 0.}, {0.835518, 0.}, {-0.012144, 0.}}]];
cols = Developer`ToPackedArray[
   List @@@ ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range[Length[sol]]]];
colorize = Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {cols, _Real, 2}},
   Compile`GetElement[cols, a],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

δx = 0.003;
maxiter = 10;
tab = newtonize[
     Outer[List, Table[N[j], {j, -2, 2, δx}], Table[N[j], {j, -2, 2, δx}]], 
     maxiter
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
newtab = ArrayReshape[
     Nearest[sol -> Automatic, Flatten[tab, 1]],
     Dimensions[tab][[1 ;; 2]]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
size = 600;

P1 = ImageRotate[
     ImageResize[Image[colorize[newtab, cols]], {size, size}]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
P1
```

> 0.578838
>
> 0.048854
>
> 0.183145
>
> 0.1231

[image]

Performing that with `δx = 0.0005` and `maxiter = 30` leads after 2 minutes to this picture:

[image]

Note also the following tweaks:

- We do no longer use a nested table for the construction of the initial points but `Outer` (among other things, this ensures that the generated array is a `PackedArray`).
- We do not `Map` a `NearestFunction` onto `tab` but rather apply `Nearest` with a syntax that enables internal low level parallelism.
- We ensure that `sol` is also a `PackedArray` so that `Nearest` can profit from this.
- We use `Image` in conjunction with a hand written method `colorize` instead of `ArrayPlot` in order to improve performance and stability (my FrontEnd had the urgent need to shut down several times).

**Update**

Corrected a bug in the `CompiledFunction`: The former version changed the value of `x` *before* the new value of `y` was computed. This was somewhat hidden by the way the code for `x` and `y` is injected into the compiled function. Buffering the new value for `x`  (in the variable `xbuffer`) remedies this.

Comment: Nice solution.  FYI, the first issue you identified was introduced in edit 4, when someone was attempting to improve the format.  By good fortune, I worked from edit 3, which did not contain this issue.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I see. So I added edit 5 ;o)

Comment: To understand why our final plots are quite different, I evaluated our respective expressions for `newton[{-2., -2.}]`, both of which yield `{-0.238379, -0.248411}`.  However, my `FixedPoint[newton, {-2., 2.}, 10]` yields `{-0.998511, -0.00312046}`, and your `newtonize[{-2., -2.}, 10]` yields `{-0.156382, -1.00541}`.  To what do you attribute the discrepancy?  By the way, where can I find the documentation for "Compile`GetElement"?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the counterexample! That really helped to debug the code (before that I assumed that this was related to some numerical errors). I corrected the bug and now the resulting picture coincides with yours now.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I am afraid there is no documentation for ``Compile`GetElement`` =o/ It pops up in the list returned by ``Sort@Compile`CompilerFunctions[]`` (see also this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) and that raised my curiosity. In some cases, `Compile` uses it as subsitute for `Part` in order to speed up code execution. When you compare the actual C-code that is generated then you see that ``Compile`GetElement`` skips checks for the array bounds when looking up indices. So, this is very fast but also a bit risky to use...